# Logtalk test returning failed when it passes under SWI interpreter

Tags: prolog, swi-prolog, logtalk

I am having an issue in which a specific test returns false when I put it in a test suite and pass it through logtalk, but returns true (which is the desired behavior) when I run it through an interpreter using the same backend compiler (SWI-Prolog).  Here is the relevant piece of the logtalk tests results, a snapshot of what the test looks like within the student directory, and the output when I pass the identical test through the SWI interpreter.

Test results:

[image]

Test case in tests.lgt:

[image]

Results from running through swipl:

[image]

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a side note, the "repeated test identifier found" errors **must** be fixed for accurate test results. Test identifiers must be unique as [documented](https://logtalk.org/manuals/devtools/lgtunit.html#test-dialects).

There's not enough information in your question for diagnosing the issue. The use of the [`{}/1`](https://logtalk.org/manuals/refman/control/external_call_1.html) control construct in the definition of the test to wrap the test goal means that the goal is called as-is. My suggestion is for you to cd to a student directory where you see the issue, and run the tests manually and then also call the test goal at the top-level. Something like:

```
$ cd student_id_xyz
$ swilgt
...
?- {tester}.
...
?- no_duplicates(..., ...).
...
```

Do this **without** restarting so that we guarantee that both tests (from the tests file and typed at the top-level) occur with the same exact context. Let us know if you get the same results.

The solution I suggested for your student grading task assumes that the student Prolog files are **plain** Prolog files (i.e. no module definitions). If that's not the case for some of the student submissions, try changing the loading of the student Prolog files in the `tester.lgt` driver files from using the `logtalk_load/1` predicate (which was selected for portability) by the Prolog backend specific predicate (e.g. `consult/1`).